# Transfer digital game from one account to another on PS4

Tags: ps4

I have a PS4 with two accounts, Account 1 and Account 2. 
Account 1 had a PS+ subscription of which games were downloaded for free and from both accounts be able to play.
The subscription already ended and the games are locked.
I tried to renew the subscription from account 1 but couldn't due to that account have a different country to the visa card... So I purchased a new subscription from account 2 that does have the same country as the visa card. I can access PS+ and download games and account 1 can play them, but I can't access to the old games that were downloaded from account 1 with the old subscription, they are locked. I already tried changing primary account, renewing licenses and still locked.
The solution seems to be to buy a subscription from account 1 due to the games were purchased from that account and the licenses belong to it, but like I said I can't.

Is there some way to transfer games or licenses from one account to another? The games were free games that PS+ gives monthly.

Answer (score 2):

### No

**Games are tied to a specific account and are not transferable.** Not only can you not transfer games from one account to another, you cannot transfer from a "master" account to one of it's "sub" accounts and visa versa.

In other words, if I bought a game, I could not give ownership to any of my child accounts. Nor could they gift me a game without first logging in with my account.

As for being free PS+ games, they are only free during the month they are offered. They have since gone back to normal price. Think of it as asking for a sale price months after the sale is over.